# Error en consola

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en C++. Que pide que en una clase de 5 alumnos, se tomaron 3 exámenes. y que debo determinar:

- A) Alumnos que aprobaron todos los exámenes.
- B) Alumnos que aprobaron al menos 1 examen.
- C) Alumnos que aprobaron solo el ultimo examen.

Y tengo que realizar un programa que permita la lectura de datos y el calculo de las estadísticas.

MI programa es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float examen1, examen2, examen3;
    int aprobadosTodos=0,aprobadosUno=0,aprobaronUltimo=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
        cout << i << ". Digite la nota del primer examen: " << examen1;cin>>examen1;
        cout << i << ". Digite la nota del segundo examen: " << examen2;cin>>examen2;
        cout << i << ". Digite la nota del tercer examen: " << examen3;cin>>examen3;
        cout << "\n";

        if((examen1>5)&&(examen2>5)&&(examen3>5)) {
            aprobadosTodos++;
        }
        if((examen1>5)||(examen3>5)||(examen3>5)) {
            aprobadosUno++;
        }
        if((examen1<6)&&(examen2<6)&&(examen3>6)) {
            aprobaronUltimo++;
        }
    }
    cout << "\nAlumnos que aprobaron todos los examenes: " << aprobadosTodos << endl;
    cout << "Alumnos que aprobaron al menos un examen: " << aprobadosUno << endl;
    cout << "Alumnos que aprobaron solo el ultimo examen: " << aprobaronUltimo << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Pero, mi consola, cada vez que inicio el programa, al ingresar una variable, aparecen números randoms, y no entiendo de donde salen:

```
1. Digite la nota del primer examen: 4.58435e-413
1. Digite la nota del segundo examen: -7.77388e+093
1. Digite la nota del tercer examen: 4.58435e-411

2. Digite la nota del primer examen: 35
2. Digite la nota del segundo examen: 36
2. Digite la nota del tercer examen: 17

3. Digite la nota del primer examen: 52 
3. Digite la nota del segundo examen: 64
3. Digite la nota del tercer examen: 710

4. Digite la nota del primer examen: 23
4. Digite la nota del segundo examen: 44
4. Digite la nota del tercer examen: 1056

5. Digite la nota del primer examen: 39
5. Digite la nota del segundo examen: 49
5. Digite la nota del tercer examen: 569


Alumnos que aprobaron todos los examenes: 1
Alumnos que aprobaron al menos un examen: 4
Alumnos que aprobaron solo el ultimo examen: 2
```

A que se debe?
PD: tengo Linux Ubuntu, influye?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los números aleatorios que ves se deben a qué imprimes las variables sin haberlas inicializado. Tienen "basura", porque la memoria quedó como la dejó otro proceso al trabajar con ella.

Si inicializas las variables:

```
float examen1 = 0, examen2 = 0, examen3 = 0;
```

Obtendrás la siguiente salida:

```
1. Digite la nota del primer examen: 0
1. Digite la nota del segundo examen: 0
1. Digite la nota del tercer examen: 0
```

Nota que se imprime 0 porque escribiste el código de modo que primero se imprime la variable y luego se lee el valor ingresado.

Si no quieres que esto suceda, puedes cambiar el orden de las instrucciones, pedir los datos primero y luego procesarlos o reescribir el código hasta que quede como quieres. Por ejemplo:

```
cout << i << ". Digite la nota del primer examen: ";
cin>>examen1;
```